# SalesForce REST API cURL to Java or Web Browser

Tags: java, rest, curl, salesforce, restful-url

I have gotten Salesforce REST API to work via cURL, as the below quoted command passes into cmd prompt and returns all the leads in Salesforce.

I also have these values:   Access  Token,  AuthorizationUrl, Customerkey, Customersecret,  id (I believe Salesforce ID),  instanceURL, loginURL, issuedat,  refreshToken, and signature.

Instead of getting the result in cmd prompt via cURL, I wish to get it in the Browser and/or via a java application.

The reason is to allow a third party (java) application call this REST API to extract and parse the leads.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

> curl -v https://na22.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/lead -H "Authorization:Bearer 00D15000000FaI8/!ASAAQFLdTJ7lhkru9y9HA7iIPOPwjb3a8uORHjCPCtNB9pSWWeFeIJ_Q4QOA6tU3Kq2kmQby7CH4sigoTBhCjE3NlJ6uLvN3" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"

Answer (score 0):

We can use Spring's RestTemplate to call any REST API. [Here](https://svenfila.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/resttemplate-with-custom-http-headers/) is an example of how to use rest template with custom headers. Also, if the response type is json then we can use Jackson to cast response into object and access the fields as explained [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-rest-template-example/).